# Retrofit Headers and Body Kotlin

Tags: api, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a question regarding retrofit.
I am making a request to a service through POST, and I need to add Header and Body.
What is the correct way to do it, or at least functional. I have tried with the following line without success.

```
interface Service{
    @Headers(
            "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.full+json",
            "Token : {myToken}")
    @POST("pet/list")
    fun getPets(@Path("myToken")token: String, @Body body: TheBody): Call<PetList>
}
class TheBody(var userId: String,
              var auth: String)
```

Comment: @Path will only work for path parameters. for header you can pass `@Header("Token")`  token in fun getPets.

Comment: Can I use 2 headers with the body in the function?   fun getPets (@Header("Accept") Accept: String, @Header("Token") Token : String, @Body body : TheBody). Something like this?

Comment: Yes, for that you can use `@HeaderMap` and pass the hashmap of key, value pair

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using interface and annotations you could do something like this

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import io.reactivex.Single
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Header
import retrofit2.http.Path
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface MoviesApi {

    @GET("/key")
    fun  getKey(
            @Query("email") email: String)
            : Single<Dto.KeyResponse>

    @GET("/movies")
    fun  getMovies(
            @Header("api-key") apiKey: String, // DEFINE HEADER HERE
            @Query("page") page: Int,
            @Query("sort") sort: String,
            @Query("q") querySearch: String)
            : Single<List<Dto.MovieResponse>>

    sealed class Dto {
        data class KeyResponse(
                @SerializedName("key") val key: String,
                @SerializedName("email") val email: String
        ) : Dto()

        data class MovieResponse(
                @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
                @SerializedName("title") val title: String,
                @SerializedName("description") val description: String,
                @SerializedName("image") val image: String
        ) : Dto()
    }
}
```